# Restrict Dot( . ) in Datagridview Cell at start of the Cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am developing an Point of Sale application in C# dot Net which contains a datagridview.

I want to restrict some cells value of datagridview to following thing.

- Do not enter a Dot(".") at the beginning of the cell (This is really needed).
- Do not enter any alphabet or any other character. (I have developed this but needed an improved idea)
- Only Enter Numerical values with negative numbers too. (I have developed this but needed an improved idea)

Guide my in this case.

Following is my Code

```
 private void Numeric_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.' && e.KeyChar != 46)
    //if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
      e.Handled = true;
    }
    // only allow one decimal point
    if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1) && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') != 1))
    {
      e.Handled = true;
    }
} 

    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Numeric_KeyPress);
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
            {
                TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
                if (tb != null)
                {                     
                    tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Numeric_KeyPress);
                }
            }

}
```

Comment: Do you use data binding? And show us your code.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I hv updated my question with code.

Comment: Different cultures uses are different separators whole and a fractional part of the number (for example, a comma in Russian), as well as other formats. So throw out your code and do validation of the entered value after user input, in accordance with the current user culture.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to handle the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event.

I'm using a regular expression to validate the value. This code allows you to enter only numbers including negative.

```
private void DataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cell = dataGridView.CurrentCell;
    if (cell.ColumnIndex != 1)
        return;

    string value = cell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
    string pattern = @"^-$ | ^-?0$ | ^-?0\.\d*$ | ^-?[1-9]\d*\.?\d*$";

    if (Regex.IsMatch(value, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace))
    {
        dataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView.CancelEdit();
    }
}
```

Note: this code will not allow users to enter numbers in their own culture.